# Move onto next task in ansible without waiting for other hosts to finish that task

Tags: wait, ansible

So I have noticed that in my ansible playbooks, if I target multiple hosts with the same playbook that each task must be complete for all hosts before it moves onto the next task.

Is it possible to define the playbook such that a task, upon completion will immediately run the following task without having to wait for the task to finish on all of the other hosts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behaviour of Ansible can be controlled with [strategy plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/strategy.html).

By default Ansible uses the linear plugin:

> All hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task, using the number of forks (default 5) to parallelize.

Another strategy available is `free`:

> Task execution is in lockstep per host batch as defined by serial (default all). Up to the fork limit of hosts will execute each task at the same time and then the next series of hosts until the batch is done, before going on to the next task.

Set the strategy like this:

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
```

If it is not possible to use `free` strategy you could set batches with the `serial` directive.